# How to convert existing json object into a java map

Tags: java, json, data-structures

Sorry guys if title dose not seems to be clear, I didn't know what to put on title exactly.
So, basically I am trying to convert a single json object into a map how could I possibly do it
for example I have json file named Animal

```
'''
{
    "Herbivores":"Cow",
    "Carnivores":{"Lion":"Den","Chettah":"Savannas","Tiger":"liar"},
    "Omnivores":"Monkey"
}
'''
```

How to convert only Carnivores into a map in java, like my expectation is:
{Lion=Den,Chettah=Savannas,Tiger=liar}

I have tried to read the value as a Input stream in java main file using fileInputStream

```
'''
      InputStream getJsonValue = new InputStream(Animals.get("Carnivores"));
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Map<String, String> myMap = mapper.readValue(getJsonValue,Map.class);

      System.out.println(myMap);
'''
```

This is giving me output as,

```
'''
     {Lion=Den,Chettah=Savannas,Tiger=liar} (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect). 
'''
```

Please let me know why "**(The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect).**" appearing after printing all values and how to solve this.

Also please let me know if there is efficient way to solve this.

Comment: `Animals.get("Carnivores")` indicates you already have that map. Why are you trying to pass that ton an input stream? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Note that you could use the `readTree()` method of `ObjectMapper` to get a tree represening your json which basically consists of nested maps and lists. Then just extract the "carnivores" sub map.